# Paypal getting access token bad request from php-curl but working fine from terminal

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am trying to make a curl request to Paypal sandbox to get access token but every time when I make a request to this url

`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1`

It sends back a 400 in response.I have tried sending curl request to any test url too and I get a 200 response.Moreover, if I send a request via terminal the reponse is 200 issue is only occuring with php-curl.Another noticable thing is this request works fine on localhost it only gets 400 on live server.

This is how i am making the curl request

```
        $username = $params['paypal_client_id'];
        $password = $params['paypal_secret'];
        $headers = array(
            "Accept-Language: en_US",
            "Accept: application/json"
            );      
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, trim($username) . ':' . trim($password));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is how i am making request via terminal

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -u "{Client_id}:{Client_secret}" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

The response i am getting is

```
Verbose info :* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#1)
*   Trying 173.0.82.78...
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#1)
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com,OU=PayPal Production,O="PayPal, Inc.",L=San Jose,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Aug 21 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*   expire date: Aug 20 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*   common name: api.sandbox.paypal.com
*   issuer: CN=DigiCert Global CA G2,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
* Server auth using Basic with user 'client_id'
> POST /v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic 'client_id'
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept-Language: en_US
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: -1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2019 12:23:30 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 338
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
* Closing connection 1
```

Any help regarding this issue will be really appreciated Thanks.

Comment: "Moreover, if I send a request via terminal " ...please show us how you do this, for comparison. Please also provide relevant links to the API documentation so we can understand how the request is meant to be structured. Also precisely what is the content of the error message you get back when you get a 400? Please paste it into your question.

Comment: And lastly...if you find it works ok in one environment but not another, then almost certainly the code is not the issue, it will instead be config, or missing variable values. Perhaps the API does not recognise your live environment as a valid client, or perhaps you've stored the wrong credentials in your live environment. None of that is anything we can help you with directly, we can only suggest things for you to check.

Comment: Hey @ADyson Thanks for your response i have updated the question and have added the command by which i am getting 200 in response also I am testing it yet on sandbox only.

Comment: Ok well one thing I notice is that in the PHP I don't see anywhere that you replicate the sending of the `grant_type=client_credentials` data which is present in the terminal version. So firstly please add that to your PHP version. However if you claim that the PHP version works in localhost and only fails in live, then I'm not sure if that's directly the problem. Have you checked the other things I mentioned - e.g. the config in your live environment?

Comment: P.S. you haven't yet updated the question with the full precise text of the error message coming in the 400 response from the server. Normally in the response body there will be some fuller explanation of the issue. Nor have you provided a link to the API docs, as requested. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson added error please have a look.

Comment: that's useful although it looks like some other debug output, not just the response from the remote server. And it only shows the response headers, not the body. What I mean is after `$data = curl_exec($ch); `, what does `var_dump($data);` show you, in the case where you get a 400 response?

Comment: this is the direct response from paypal

`Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.Apache Server at api.sandbox.paypal.com Port 443`

Comment: hm that's not very useful really :-s

Comment: Have you looked into Abulafia's answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54327486/5947043)? It's perhaps worth trying out those various suggestions to see if it would help you diagnose (or avoid) the problem. The SSL error does seem like a strong possibility given that you seem to have a difference between local and live environments...it could easily be that the config is different in PHP in relation to that.

Comment: Fixed it thanks @ADyson updating curl did the thing

Comment: that's great. You know you should post your answer here for others to learn from (and so they can upvote you). It's completely allowed to answer your own question - you can just write something in the "Your Answer" section below, same as any other user.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already point out, it's hard to debug this remotely. I lack reputation to add a comment, so will suggest this answer instead. This is a complex problem, so I'm afraid this answer will, at best, point you in the right direction rather than give you a specific walk-through.

Firstly, you would be much better off using the paypal PHP SDK which at the time of writing can be found on this page:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/

If that link is broken, I'm sure Google will assist. This will almost certainly solve your problems.

However, to answer your question (or that of anyone else who, for some reason, can't use the canonical library) - as can be seen from the link above, Paypal are quite strict about their security. I strongly suspect that your command line curl is using a different SSL connection protocols from your php-curl. I would be surprised if this page didn't answer solve your problem:

https://github.com/paypal/tls-update#php

I have reproduced it here in case of link breakage:

> PHP requirements
>
> PHP uses the system-supplied cURL library, which requires OpenSSL 1.0.1c or later. You might need to update your SSL/TLS libraries.
>
> Guidelines
>
> Find OpenSSL in these locations:
>
> OpenSSL installed in your operating system's openssl version.
>
> OpenSSL extension installed in your PHP. Find this in your php.ini.
>
> OpenSSL used by PHP_CURL - curl_version().
>
> These OpenSSL extensions can be different, and you update each one separately.
>
> PayPal and other PHP SDKs use the same OpenSSL extension that PHP_CURL uses to make HTTP connections. The PHP_CURL OpenSSL extension must support TLSv1.2.
>
> The php_curl library uses its own version of the OpenSSL library, which is not the same version that PHP uses, which is the openssl.so file in php.ini.
>
> To verify your PHP and TLS versions
>
> To find the openssl_version information for cURL, run:
>
> php -r 'echo json_encode(curl_version(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);'
>
> The returned php_curl version might be different from the openssl version because they are different components.
>
> When you update your OpenSSL libraries, you must update the php_curl OpenSSL version and not the OS OpenSSL version.
>
> Download cacert.pem and TlsCheck.php.
>
> In a shell on your production system, run:
>
> php -f TlsCheck.php
>
> On success:
>
> PayPal_Connection_OK
>
> On failure:
>
> curl_error information
>
> Notes:
>
> Make sure that your command line test uses the same versions of PHP and SSL/TLS libraries that your web server uses.
>   If you use MAMP or XAMPP as your development set up, the PHP that is packaged with them uses an earlier version of OpenSSL, which you cannot easily update. For more information about this issue and a temporary workaround, see Unknown SSL protocol error.

One final thing - if this is the cause of your error, I'm going to assume your live server is at least a couple of years old. It's totally unrelated and none of my business, but if it's that out of date you probably have a whole bunch of other vulnerabilities. I would strongly suggest updating or even spinning up a new server (which may well be easier said than done...)

Comment: If there was a problem with SSL certificates I don't think OP would even get as far as making the request and getting back a 400 HTTP status. Instead it would fail to make the handshake and would not send any request at all.

Comment: According to their docs:

https://www.paypal-notice.com/en/TLS-1.2-and-HTTP1.1-Upgrade/

(Find 'On Failure' on page)

Bad requests will return a 400 error

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's a useful clarification. I think I was getting confused between SSL/TLS protocol version and an actual invalid certificate (which would definitely cause a problem)

Comment: If you see the latest comments though it would appear the OP is not getting either of the error messages detailed in your link

Comment: Indeed. The OP could perhaps attempt to ping that API point, though. I was merely asserting that 400 was a valid symptom rather than handshake failure. The endpoint it specifically designed to test this very situation. It can be found at: https://tlstest.paypal.com
To clarify my point I am in no way convinced by my theory, but this seems a quick way to establish one way or the other.

Comment: That's true...possibly the endpoint they're calling now doesn't return the same message, even if the cause is similar.

Comment: My thoughts exactly